# PHP in HTML comes out as syntax error

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo some HTML with PHP as well as there is a PHP variable inside which comes out as `syntax error`.

The line:

```
<td><?php if($value['search_id'] == 0){echo 'False Search';}else{echo '<a href="https://google.com/search/".$value['search_id'].""</a>';} ?></td>
```

Comment: You have very mismatched quotes and very broken HTML here: `'<a href="https://google.com/search/".$value['search_id'].""</a>'`  Maybe you meant this?: `'<a href="https://google.com/search/'.$value['search_id'].'">some link text</a>'`

Comment: <td>
<?php if($value['search_id'] == 0)
{echo 'False Search';}
 else{echo "<a href='https://google.com/search/".$value['search_id']."YOUR TEXT HERE </a>";}
 ?>
 </td>

Comment: Replace your code with: <?php if($value['search_id'] == 0){echo 'False Search';}else{echo '<a href="yourdomain.com"'.$value['search_id'].'"</a>';} ?>